# question about chroot

Tags: ubuntu, chroot

I used chroot to install Debian Lenny on my Ubuntu desktop. I have now decided I will no longer be using Debian and so I want to remove Debian and install Ubuntu server in a chroot instead.

My question is, I can simply remove the /chroot/debian/lenny folder and create a new chroot for Ubuntu server? or is there something else I need to do (I have read a bit about chroot but it does not answer this question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't setup any services or scripts in the base filesystem that points into the chroot then all you have to do is delete the directory.

If you are worried, you could of course temporarily rename the directory to something else and reboot.  If everything that is supposed to come up does then delete/archive the old chroot.

Comment: fair enough - sound advice. I think I'll simply rename the folder for now.